# How to change My Wishlist text in top links in magento

Tags: magento

I want to change My wishlist text to "Wishlist" in top links in magento.

I tried in `magentotest\app\design\frontend\default\magentotest\layout\wishlist.xml` file 
But I am not getting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Copy the file `app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Links.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Wishlist/Block/` and change the `_createLabel()` method as you need

Comment: @MohammadFaisal The file is copyed from the core folder to local folder and then edited. Magento will search for the file in local first.

Comment: Also, most of this stuff can be taken care of through the translation table instead of mangling template files.

Answer (score 0):

you can aslo edit you local files
Mage_Whishlist.csv